# Copy paste and delete entire row based on if column A has "xyz"

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I am looking to copy paste and delete a entire row based on if Column A has"xyz"
ie:If A1="xyz" then copy paste(a1:g1) into next blank row and delete row 1:1.

Comment: 1. Do you want to paste in same sheet or other sheet? 2. What do you mean by Next Balnk row, Is it after the last row of sheet or in between blank rows in sheet?

Comment: On same sheet, last row of the sheet

Comment: See if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) helps

Comment: Is it only the one row (i.e. row 1) or do you want to loop through a range?

Comment: Its a loop through a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom sort that places *xyz* after all else might be the better solution. If you need to *copy/paste/delete* then remember that it is always best to start at the bottom and work up in your `For ... Next` loop when deleting rows.

```
Dim r As Long, lr As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = lr To 1 Step -1
        If LCase(.Cells(r, 1)) = "abc" Then
            .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, .Cells(r, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Copy _
              Destination:=.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
End With
```

Comment: @pnuts - That *abc* Easter egg has traditionally been a tough nut to crack. :)